# dual vectors and coordinate function under group transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

I'm coming from a physics background and currently reading through P. Woit's [Quantum Theory, Groups and Representations](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319646107) (a free final draft pdf can be found [here](http://www.math.columbia.edu/%7Ewoit/QMbook/qmbook.pdf)).  Enjoying the read but I'm a bit confused by some of the mathematics in certain derivations and hoping someone could clear things out.  It seemed more appropriate here in Math.SE than in Physiscs.SE.

- On p37 the induced representation of a group $G$ on the dual vector space $V^*$ is discussed.  I'm confused by the last two matrix equations before 4.3.  For a representation $\pi(g)$ on $V$ with matrix $P$, the induced dual representation for a $l\in V^*$ with components $l_i$ for the dual basis, is then written in matrix form as 
  $$(l_1 \ldots l_n) \to (l_1 \ldots l_n)(P^{-1})^T,$$
  and similarly for the transpose expression.  I was expecting just $(P^{-1})$ there as the induced representation on the dual is $(\pi^{-1})^t$ as written in 4.2.  Also for $v \in V$ it doesn't seem to keep $l(v)$ invariant as stated if I read this as
  $$ l(v) = [l] [v] \to ((\pi^{-1})^t(g)l)(\pi(g)v)=[l][P^{-1}]^T[P][v],$$
  with $[l]$ the components of $l$ as row matrix, $[v]$ components of $v$ as column matrix.  Or am I missing something in his matrix notation?  Maybe unrelated but an equation like 6.14 on p191 also doesn't make sense to me...
- In Sec. 8.2 (p97) the irreps of $SU(2)$ are constructed by looking at the action of $su(2)$ basis elements on the vector space of homogeneous polynomials on $\mathbb{C}^2$.  I've seen similar derivations before, but slightly different.  Here the functions are considered as functions of coordinate functions $z_1, z_2$ (thus basis vectors of $V^*$) whereas in other sources (for instance *N. Jeevanjee, An Introduction to Tensors and Group Theory for Physicists* on p246) the $z_1,z_2$ are considered as components in $V$.  Between the two derivations the highest weight functions are different (the order from highest to lowest is basically reversed) so I'm wondering if one of the two is "wrong" here? $^a$
  I understand that for $f: V\to \mathbb{C}$, 
  $$f(v)\overset{g}{\to}{f(g^{-1}v)},$$
  and if one takes $z_1,z_2$ as the components of $v$, one arrives $z_2^l$ as the highest weight vector for homogenous polynomials of degree $l$ (see f.i. the Jeevanjee ref.).

  In the Woit book one has a function $f(z)$ (with $z$ shorthand for the coordinate functions $z_1,z_2$ as basis of $V^*$) and it is written
  $$f(z)\overset{g}{\to} f(g^Tz), \qquad (1)$$
  and in the end one gets $z_1^l$ as the highest weight vector.  I don't really understand the transformation of $f(z)$ here.  The equations discussed in the first bullet are given as justification for it, so that adds to my confusion of course.  My reasoning was, (1)  would imply 
  $$ z\overset{g}{\to}(g^T)^{-1}z \qquad (2)$$ 
  to keep $f(z)$ invariant.  But I thought we had $v \to gv$ for components on $V$, $l \to (g^{-1})^Tl$ on components on $V^*$, and $z\to g^{-1}z$ for the basis on $V^*$ (bottom p35), which seems to contradict (2).  So I'm missing something there as well.

---

$^a$If it means anything: the method used in the Woit book with transformations of functions of coordinate functions yields the right Lie algebra isomorphism between homogeneous polynomials of degree 2 on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $sl(2,\mathbb{R})$ when discussed on p188-189.  While it doesn't seem to do when I try to other approach using transformations of functions of components (but I might have to change the isomorphism relation in that case as well?).